# I want to dynamicly update the data that I get from an api but I don´t know how to do this

Tags: angular, httpclient

I have a spring boot api that works with a postgresql database. My frontend is an angular application. I am working with the HttpClient. Now I always have to refrsh the website to fetch new data from my api. My question is: How can I fetch new data without refreshing the website??

Service:

```
getMaxId() : Observable<object> 
    {
        return this.client.get(url);
    }
```

Typscript file:

```
export class AktuelleWerteComponent implements OnInit {
  
  messwerte : any; 
  maxId : any;

  constructor(private service : MesswerteService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getMaxId().subscribe(data => {
      this.maxId = data;
    })
  }

}
```

HTML file:

```
<p style="font-size: 50px;">{{maxId.temperatur}}°C</p>
```

I hope someone can help me with my Problem.

Comment: The important question is, when do you want the data to be reloaded? On a certain user action, an interval, or route navigation?

Answer (score 1):

you didn't specify what is your needs exactly, so I will write here two options.

1. WebSocket - this is a technology that let's you create an open connection
   between server and client, you can start with this [Docks](https://socket.io/docs/v4/), this option is for an app that needs an open stream - like chat apps.
2. you can put your code inside `interval` :

```
 `setInterval(() => { 
   // you API request
  }, 1000)
```

also, you can use `interval()` of `rxjs`, see this [link](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/interval)

good luck :)

Comment: Thank you! The setInterval function is perfect for my use

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by http polling.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/recipes/http-polling